# Segfault on inserting into std::vector with insert member function of std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, iterator

When I insert into the vector like this :

```
resVec.insert(frontIter , vec[idx]);
```

I get a seg fault , but if I do

```
*frontIter = vec[idx];
```

It works without any problems. I know that the []operator has the capacity to allocate space for the object and then insert it, is the error that insert does not allocate space and it needs the space to be already allocated when insert is called at a position ?

I think this error is due to my confusion about what this does :

```
vi vec(10);
```

Is this similar to `vec.resize(10)` or `vec.reserve(10)`

Also does insert not work as say position 9 after I have called vec.reserve(10) ?

This is the code segment, just to make sure that I am not missing anything.

```
using vi = std::vector<int>;
using size = std::size_t;

// return vi after partition 
vi partition_space(const vi & vec, size n)
{
    vi resVec(vec.size());      

    int partVal = vec[n];   
    //resVec[n] = partVal;

    // iterators to the back and front of the resVec. 
    // insertion will happen at the iters
    vi::iterator frontIter = resVec.begin();
    vi::reverse_iterator backIter = resVec.rbegin();    

    for(size idx = 0 ; idx < vec.size() ; ++idx)
    {
        if(idx == n) 
        {
            continue;
        }   

        if(vec[idx] < partVal) // insert in front of  partVal
        {
//          *frontIter = vec[idx];
            resVec.insert(frontIter , vec[idx]);
            ++frontIter;    
        }
        else if(vec[idx] > partVal)// insert at back of n
        {
            *backIter = vec[idx];
            ++backIter;
        }
        else // repeated elements .. random choose to put it in front.. both choice does not matter
        {
            //resVec.insert(frontIter , vec[idx]);  
            *frontIter = vec[idx];
            ++frontIter;
        }
    }

    frontIter++; 

    if(!std::distance(frontIter , backIter.base()))
    {
        std::cout << " ! " << std::endl;
    }

    *backIter = partVal;

    return resVec ; // nrvo
}
```

Comment: `vec[index]` doesn't allocate space for a new item and then insert it at `index`, it provides a reference to the item at `index`. `vec[index] = value;` sets the item at `index` equal to `value`.

Comment: if `vi vec(10);` is meant to be `vector vec(10)`  it is a resize, not a reserve.

Comment: @jaggedSpire I guess I messed it up with the [] operators for std::map . std::map's thing does the insertion too.

Comment: @nnrales map behaves differently, as it is a different data structure.

Comment: yep, I though the behaviours of these standard operators might be the same. My bad

Comment: An easy mistake when first learning the language. Perhaps think of operators as syntax sugar that does something logical/convenient for the most common use case of the data structure, rather than something with a universal meaning.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Thanks, that makes sense

Comment: @nnrales What exactly is your code supposed to accomplish?  Why not use `std::partition` or `std::stable_partition`?  Those functions partition elements in a container and returns an iterator to where the partition starts.  STL algorithms are powerful things if you know them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie building the wheel to understand the wheel better .

Comment: @nnrales Well, you don't need to look far to see how [partitioning is done](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition).  See the "Possible Implementation" section.

Comment: Probably `auto iter = std::partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](int val) { return val < v[n]; }); return vi(vec.begin(), iter);` would have done the same job as your entire function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie haha. Thanks I did not know about that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  I think the seg fault happens, because I am calling insert, which invalidates the iterator that I have pointing at the end. Could this be a possible cause from your experience ?

Comment: Well, if you have iterators pointing to a vector's elements, and you resize that vector, then the iterators are indeed invalidated.   I would just copy the contents of `vec` to resvec, call `std::partition`, and resize resvec up to the iterator that `partition` returns.  I'm assuming you want to get the elements that are less than `vec[n]` and return them?

Comment: @nnrales `{ vi resvec = vec; auto iter = partition(resvec.begin(), resvec.end(), [&](int val) { return val < vec[n];}); resvec.erase(iter, resvec.end()); return resvec; }`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How do learn all these cools things ? Do you have a good tutorial you follow or just from experience and reading the documentation ?

Comment: @nnrales -- It takes experience, but it also takes some intuition.  If you find yourself writing loops that does a job where you feel it's been done thousands of times before, there is usually an STL algorithm or set of STL algorithms that will do the same job.  Partitioning was easy, as there is an algorithm called `std::partition`, while some other job may not be so obvious.  Sean Parent has done many talks on this, i.e. to get out of the `for-loop` habit and discover if there are algorithms that do the job.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for Sean Parent. I just watched his C++ Seasoning talk and it was beautiful ! Now raw loops , less synchronization / task model , no shared pointers and a lot of interesting, mind-blowing tidbits. It kind of makes me sad too, as I keep understanding that I know nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is due to invalidation of iterator `frontIter` after first insert is happened. Here is whats going on:

1. Code allocate vector `vec` with 10 elements in it.
2. New element is inserted into position `frontIter`, this trigger vector storage re-allocation because vector out of it capacity so insert code reallocate inner storage to accommodate the insert. So this operation invalidate *all* `vec` iterators
3. Code try to insert new element by using old (invalidated) iterator... - seg-fault!

Comment: Thank you ! I had to spend some time to figure that yout.